# Swift - Reload the last 20 rows in A UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm working on a news page in an app and am attempting to reload the last 20 rows in a `TableView` controller whenever a fetch request is made to our API. Results are loaded in batches of 20, and I'd prefer not to reload the whole `TableView` whenever 20 more results are added to the table, as this causes flickering on fast scrolling.

I know I should use `self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths()`, but I'm not sure as to how I obtain the index paths of last 20 rows in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a for loop...

if there are 30 rows, this method will reload the last 20 rows (row 10 - 30). Remember, the index paths start at row 0 not 1.

```
for (var i = 9; i < 29; i++) {

self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(i)

}
```